# Google SignIn button "Parameter client_id is not set correctly."

Tags: google-signin

I have added Google Sign In button to a web page according the following description - https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button

Unfortunatelly the button is displayed but it does not work.
In the console I see an error:

```
[GSI_LOGGER]: Parameter client_id is not set correctly.
```

that happens when the following script is being loaded:
https://accounts.google.com/gsi/button

Could anyone of you experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has encountered the same problems - I found a root cause - `prototype` (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js`) script somehow interfered with google sign in button.
Once I removed it, the google sign in button started working properly.